# Filter Data from table based on different combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today, we are working on SQL server query and facing one small issue in a simple logic. We have a table which is having 3 columns. You can see the structure of table as given below.

```
ID | Name | FKId
1     a       1
2     b       1
3     c       1
4     a       2
5     b       2
6     a       3
7     c       3
8     b       5
9     c       5
```

In the above table, you can see a column 'Name' which has three different type of values a,b,c and 'FKId' is a foreign key column. In our result, we need those rows where we have a combination of 'Name' column values as a,b and a,c for each 'FKId'. No other combination is accepted. In the above table, we need below result.

```
ID | Name | FKId
4     a       2
5     b       2
6     a       3
7     c       3
```

Comment: Is `Name` unique within `FKId`?

Comment: Have you made any effort to do your own homework before posting here?

Comment: yes, Combination of Name and FKId should be unique.

Comment: @TabAlleman: I was trying to resolve this issue using dense_rank() , and row_number(). Might be I am on wrong track. Actually in reality Name column is a status column.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
with fkids as (
   select fkid,
          max(case when name='a' then 1 else 0 end) as has_a,
          max(case when name='b' then 1 else 0 end) as has_b,
          max(case when name='c' then 1 else 0 end) as has_c
      from table
      group by fkid
)
select table.* from table
    join fkids on
        fkids.fkid = table.fkid and (
           (has_a = 1 and has_b = 1 and has_c = 0) or 
           (has_a = 1 and has_b = 0 and has_c = 1)
        )
```